# My Host changed MySQL Auto_increment column to two

Tags: mysql

After a recent change my host has made, all auto_increment columns are incrementing by two. After emailing my host about this, this is what they said:

> This sites is located on our new load balanced shared platform. This
>   behaviour is expected on the new cluster. The auto increment will not
>   actually affect the performance or working of the tables, and you can
>   still do counts on the tables and use any incremented columns in the
>   same way. Just if you check directly on the database you will see
>   these are incrementing by two.
>
> Eventually this behaviour will be applied to all our servers as we
>   perform this update on our entire platform.

What I would like to know: is what they are saying right? In my mind an auto increment column should increment by one and not two!!

This is going to cause a few issues with some older sites that use this to generate order numbers etc.

Everything else however that i have got will continue to work ok, its just a bit annoying.

Answer (score 3):

Disregarding the specifics of your host, if a piece of code depends on auto increment always going one by one and not having holes, then the code is wrong because that was never a guarantee.

The only guarantees you have is that the column will not have duplicates, and new rows will have the next sequence value for that column; which is usually last value + 1, but not guaranteed - the guarantee is that it will be the *next* one, so it won't go back and fill holes for example.

Comment: In my case it doesnt matter functionally if it has holes it or if they increment by two its just more of an annoyance that they dont run in seqance. I just have never come accross a host that does this.

Answer (score 1):

This is very common with a multi-master MySQL setup to prevent primary keys from clashing.

If you were to add a row to both of the load balanced servers at the same time, they'd both try to insert with an auto_increment ID of, say, 51. You'd get an error and replication would break.

So, in a two-server setup, server 1 inserts 1, 3, 5, 7, etc. and server 2 inserts 2, 4, 6, 8, etc.